# How to cancel a while loop by typing 'quit' into either of two prompts

Tags: powershell, while-loop, logical-operators

I have made a printer install script for our regional offices. It first asks you what office you are in and the asks if you want to add or remove a printer

I'm trying to enable the user to type 'quit' into either of those prompts and have the while loop exit. It currently works only if you type 'quit' into the second prompt.

I've tried

```
while ($install -ne 'quit' -AND $office -ne 'quit'){}
```

and

```
while ($install -ne 'quit' -OR $office -ne 'quit'){}
```

and the original was

```
while ($install -ne 'quit'){}
```

All work when you type it into the second prompt, which is a read-host for `$install`. If I print out the value of `$office` I can see it stores 'quit' but I've clearly missed something in the logic to get it to stop when that value is stored.

Here is the whole script (well at least enough of it to see how it works).

```
cls
$install = ''
$office = ''


while ($install -ne 'quit' -and $office -ne 'quit'){

$office = read-host Which office are you in? "(GOL, SUN, CNS, TSV)"

$install = read-host Type "add" to install, "remove" to uninstall or "quit" to quit the program


    If ($office -eq 'gol' -or $install -eq 'add'){

    add-printerport 20.45.50.32 -PrinterHostAddress 20.45.50.32
    "Adding printer port 20.45.50.32"
    ""

    add-printer -name "GOL Direct Print" -DriverName "FX ApeosPort-VII C7788 PS" -PortName 20.45.50.32
    "Adding printer GOL Direct Print AKA FX ApeosPort-VII C7788 PS at IP address 20.45.50.32"
    ""
    "Script complete, you can test printing now to 'GOL Direct Print'."

    }

    elseif ($office -eq 'gol' -and $install -eq 'remove'){

      remove-printer -name "GOL Direct Print" 
    ""
    "Removing printer GOL Direct Print"
    ""
      remove-printerport 20.45.50.32
    "Removing printer port 20.45.50.32
    ""

    "Old printer has been removed, run the script again to install"

    }
```

The script has a few more `elseif` statements in the same format as above, but that's it.

Comment: `if ($install -eq 'quit') { break }` ?

Comment: Thank you!

It didn't work at first, but I figured out  I just needed to put that line after the read-host line for $office. ahhh, so simple, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of what you're trying to achieve, you can use the [`break` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.3#break) to exit your `while` loop and you can simplify the condition using `-contains` instead of 2 `if` conditions.

The use of `.Trim()` is recommended because `-contains` will look for an exact match and any excess white space would make the condition fail.

```
while ($true) {
    $office = Read-Host "Which office are you in? '(GOL, SUN, CNS, TSV)'"
    $install = Read-Host "Type 'add' to install, 'remove' to uninstall or 'quit' to quit the program"

    if ($office.Trim(), $install.Trim() -contains 'quit') {
        break
    }

    # do other stuff here
    'hi!'
}
```